# Telerik Grid with Identical Property Names

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I'm working on a medical application where a grid needs to display the ICD description as well as its associated HCC category description.  The ICD and HCC types look like this:

```
public class ICD {
    public String Code { get; set; }

    public String Description { get; set; }

    public HCC HCC { get; set; }
}

public class HCC {
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }

    public String Description { get; set; }
}
```

When I bind the Telerik MVC extensions grid to a list of ICD objects, I'm setting up the columns like so:

```
this.Html.Telerik().Grid(this.Model.ICDs)
    .Name("ICDGrid")
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(icd => icd.Code))
    .DataBinding(binding => {
        binding.Ajax().Select(this.Model.AjaxSelectMethod);
        binding.Ajax().Update(this.Model.AjaxUpdateMethod);
    })
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(icd => icd.ICDType.Name).Title("ICD 9/10");
        columns.Bound(icd => icd.Code);
        columns.Bound(icd => icd.Description);
        columns.Bound(icd => icd.HCC.Description).Title("HCC Category")
        columns.Command(commands => commands.Delete()).Title("Actions").Width(90);
    })
    .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).DefaultDataItem(new ICD()))
    .ToolBar(commands => {
        commands.Insert();
        commands.SubmitChanges();
    })
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(12))
    .Render();
```

The problem is that both ICD and HCC have properties named "Description", and I have no control over that. Is there a way to tell Telerik to call them different things in the JavaScript it generates? Something like ICDDescription and HCCDescription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you cannot alias the properties. What you can do is create a ViewModel object with where the properties are named uniquely. Then bind the grid to the ViewModel object. Here is a code snippet:

```
public class ICDViewModel
{
   public string Description
   {
      get;
      set;
   }
   public string HCCDescription
   {
      get;
      set;
   }
   // The rest of the properties of the original ICD class
}
```

Then you need to change the type of Model.ICDs to use ICDViewModel. You can use the `Select` extension method to map ICD to ICDViewModel:

```
Model.ICDs = icds.Select(icd => new ICDViewModel 
{ 
   Description = icd.Description,
   HCCDescription = icd.HCC.Description
   /* set the rest of the ICD properties */
});
```

Comment: Yep, I had sort of wanted to avoid that as the ICD and HCC classes are already part of a view model. Oh well...can't have it all. Thanks for your answer!